# R logical operators with multiple "not" conditions

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(v1=c("a","a","b"),v2=c("c","d","d")
> df
  v1 v2
1  a  c
2  a  d
3  b  d
```

If I am interested in finding rows where **v1** equals **a** *and* **v2** equals **d**, I can use:

```
> with(df,v1=="a" & v2=="d")
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If I am interested in finding rows where **v1** *is not* **a** *and* **v2** *is not* **d** I though this should work:

```
> with(df,v1!="a" & v2!="d")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

However, using the *or* operator seems to give the result I want, but I'm not clear why:

```
> with(df,v1!="a" | v2!="d")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Clearly I am missing something basic here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems to work perfectly. Remember that for the "and" operator to be TRUE, *both* conditions need to be TRUE. But none of the rows satifies both `v1!="a"`and `v2!="d"` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to correctly figure out what is going on with booleans, is replacing [image] and [image] values for [image] and [image] respectively on the one hand, and replacing AND ([image]) and OR ([image]) logical operators for [image] and [image] on the other hand. Thus ***for the first components only***,

One understands `with(df,v1=="a" & v2=="d")[1]` as

[image]

`with(df,v1!="a" & v2!="d")[1]` as

[image]

And `with(df,v1!="a" | v2!="d")[1]` as

[image]

where the symbol $\neg$ is the logical negation i.e. the logical *not*.

---

You may want to test the validity of this approach

```
> FALSE*FALSE 
[1] 0
> FALSE*TRUE
[1] 0
> FALSE+TRUE
[1] 1
```

---

Also note that

[image]

Indeed,

```
> TRUE+TRUE
[1] 2
> !!2
[1] TRUE
```